# Error building the network on HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working on this [Hyperledger Fabric tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

When I'm trying to build the network by running the script `byfn.sh`:

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
```

The console shows me this error:

[image]

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: I doubt that _you_ can do anything to fix this, as this appears to be a bug in some program run by `byfn.sh`. Try contacting its developers.

Comment: Hi Diogo, please add the OS/platform you are using, the version of fabric etc.

Comment: Hi! I'm using ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine. The weird thing is that i could generate the network but now i can't and don't know why

Comment: is there stack trace available to see where it fails?

Comment: What version of Go are you running?

Comment: @vikas-banage suggested an edit with the [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI2V9.png)